# Unable to fit this layout to multiple screen resolution in android

Tags: android

i have a Relative layout which has some buttons and imagebuttons with tabbar in bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView android:id="@+id/statustext" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor = "@color/white" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Welcome to www.****.com" android:layout_weight = "1" />

   <EditText android:id="@+id/welcome" android:hint="Please enter your name" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="center" android:singleLine="true" 
          android:layout_below = @+id/statustext"  android:cursorVisible = "false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1" >
   </EditText>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_below = "@+id/welcome">
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="new user" android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"        android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/welcome"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button4" android:text="Registered?" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button7" android:text="Forgot Pass" android:layout_below="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button10" android:text="Email" android:layout_below="@+id/button7" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button7"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Sign-In" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button5" android:text="Username" android:layout_below="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button8" android:text="Password" android:layout_below="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button11" android:text="Cart" android:layout_below="@+id/button8" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Search" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button6" android:text="Call *****" android:layout_below="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button9" android:text="Register" android:layout_below="@+id/button6" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight = "1"   android:id="@+id/button12" android:text="Follow Us" android:layout_below="@+id/button9" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/bluebutton" android:layout_below = "@id/button10" android:layout_weight = "1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"  android:background="@drawable/blue_logo"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/bluebutton" android:layout_below = "@id/button11" android:layout_weight = "1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="103dp"   android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/dialer" android:background="@drawable/orange_logo"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/blackbutton"  android:layout_below = "@id/button12" android:layout_weight = "1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="103dp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orangebutton"  android:background="@drawable/black_logo" ></Button>
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that i looks fine in Google Nexus(H-533 ,W-320) calculated by

```
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    Log.i("Screen Height = ",Integer.toString(screenHeight) );
    Log.i("Screen Width = ",Integer.toString(screenWidth) );
```

and i have created different folders according to resolution,its taking xml from

```
layout-normal-mdpi
```

when i see this layout in HTC legend(H - 480 W-320) Or Samsung Ace the last three image buttons looking compressed about half of their height between normal button and Tabbar.The problem i guess in the small height with respect to Nexus, and all three devices are using same mdpi resolution xml file .So what should i do to make this layout work according to diff screen heights of same mdpi resolution devices.

If thats not possible from layout

> weight

can i change button size programmatically after calculating screen size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check this revised version and if problem persist comment me

```
enter code here`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/statustext" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to www.****.com" android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/welcome" android:hint="Please enter your name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="center"
    android:singleLine="true" android:layout_below="@+id/statustext"
    android:cursorVisible="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_below="@+id/welcome">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linlayout1">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="new user"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Sign-In"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linlayout2">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button4" android:text="Registered?"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button5" android:text="Username"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button6" android:text="Call *****"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linlayout3">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button7" android:text="Forgot Pass"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button8" android:text="Password"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button9" android:text="Register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linlayout4">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button10" android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button11" android:text="Cart"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button12" android:text="Follow Us"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linlayout4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linlayout5">
        <Button android:id="@+id/bluebutton" android:layout_below="@id/button10"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/blue_logo"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/bluebutton" android:layout_below="@id/button11"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/orange_logo"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/blackbutton" android:layout_below="@id/button12"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/black_logo"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

and yes please dont forget to write in your manifest file under application tag ending

```
</application>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

'

this will do your full work

thanks and enjoy happy coding

Comment: Thanks abhinav for the answer.I got it working with help of your code.    Actually i figured it out from ur code and changed it in my manifest file value of "android:anyDensity="true" was set to false,so it was taking only layout-normal-mdpi for all normal screens.As i changed it to true it worked.By the way i am going to check your layout as well but can you please tell me what was the problem in my layout i was also using android:layout_weight="1" in my relative layout.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rishi, android:layout_weight="anything" specifies particular widgit/layout authority in that particular layout for eg. if set to 1 then it will be fully qualified i.e. by % it will take 100% space of that layout, if set to .80 the 80% so weight specifies overall weight of that particular value in layout. In your code it is set to one so it will get 100% space and if multiple values are there i.e. multiple it will take as according to their weight. use weight where it is applicable, My suggestion is check my layout and do it according that will help you and you will never get problem

Comment: And one more thing Rishi in your layout one button change effect all button but if you code my way change will be effected only to linear layout which can be easier to handle